# Wordpress: SQL Query to add custom field to posts with specific tag

Tags: sql, wordpress, tags

I'm trying to find a way to add a custom field to all my wordpress post that has a specific tag.
I have to add "meta_value = us" to all post that has a "apple" tag.

```
   TABLE: wp_postmeta
      meta_id = ...
      Post_id = ...
      meta_key = meta_country
      meta_value = it
```

I don't find where tag is stored.

Someone can help me with the correct query that i have to run to do that?

Answer (score 0):

All taxonomy terms, of which "tags" are, and assuming a "wp_" prefix are stored in the `wp_terms` table, which is related to `wp_term_taxonomy`, which is related to `wp_term_relationships` which is related to `wp_posts`. You can insert into the `wp_postmeta` table using the results of a queries on the former tables.

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ( `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value` )
SELECT tr.object_id, 'meta_key' AS meta_key, 'meta_value' AS meta_value
FROM wp_terms t
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON tr.taxonomy_id = tt.taxonomy_id
WHERE t.name = 'apple'
```